# Devise not displaying error messge during an authentication failure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication

I was expecting a flash notice when authentication failures occurs in devise.  But get nothing during a authentication failure, just the page refreshes and remains still. 
I didn't change any stuffs. The default devise installation itself is not displaying flash errors with invalid authentication attempt.  I just installed devise as a gem a tryed to uise it. Din't even change a word of the code that is generated.
May be I thought if is it due to some browser comparability issues.
But I get other mannually introduced flash messsages else working.

Any suggestions as to what may be broken.

I'm using rails 3.0.1
*** Update ***

I'm getting failure messages for user registration(sign up) but not for failures messages of signing in.
some googleing on this topic revealed that for sign up it expects:-
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
But for sign in it expects some other alert message tag to be referenced, but didn't get the exact info of what is that alert tag which i must use and wher to use ???

Please provide some suggestions !!!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: More information is needed, such as some code.

Comment: @Preet Sangha, "devise" is the correct spelling. It is the name of a plugin for rails. Please undo your edit for that.

Comment: I never knew that our posts can be edited by others !!! . @Zabba Will paste you my code shortly.

Comment: Yes, editing posts is possible with users > 2000 reputation and it's actually a good thing on a site like SO. It's not as dangerous as it seems. People here on SO are great.

Comment: @zabba. I just added devise in my gemfile and installed in and added users model migrated it.Just did the default stuffs. I didn't change any stuffs. The default devise installation itself is not displaying flash errors with invalid authentication attempt

Comment: unfort, i gotta go now, ttyl if this question is still unanswered till tomorrow. does the page that is being rendered contain a `<div id="flash_alert">` or with id `flash_error` ? Try adding those div's and see.

Comment: Hi Zabba , thanks for your inputs.I found out what I was missing; ;)Added the same as answer below. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [rails - Devise - Handling - devise_error_messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101641/rails-devise-handling-devise-error-messages)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Atlast after some good amount of searching/browsing I found the answer,
you have to add the following piece of code in our application.html.erb file

```
  <%- flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String) %>
  <%- end -%>
```

After adding this I was able to see the sign_in failures alert messages :).

Comment: It didn't work for me in the project using rails 5.1.3 and devise 4.3.0

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly, a bit hacky, but I'm using this helper (app/helpers/devise_helper.rb) to grab flashes and use those if set then default to `resource.errors`. This is just based on the helper that's in the devise lib.

```
module DeviseHelper

  def devise_error_messages!
    flash_alerts = []
    error_key = 'errors.messages.not_saved'

    if !flash.empty?
      flash_alerts.push(flash[:error]) if flash[:error]
      flash_alerts.push(flash[:alert]) if flash[:alert]
      flash_alerts.push(flash[:notice]) if flash[:notice]
      error_key = 'devise.failure.invalid'
    end

    return "" if resource.errors.empty? && flash_alerts.empty?
    errors = resource.errors.empty? ? flash_alerts : resource.errors.full_messages

    messages = errors.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
    sentence = I18n.t(error_key, :count    => errors.count,
                                 :resource => resource.class.model_name.human.downcase)

    html = <<-HTML
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>#{sentence}</h2>
      <ul>#{messages}</ul>
    </div>
    HTML

    html.html_safe
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I ended up here because I was having the same problem in rails 5.1 and the accepted answer didn't worked, so here's what I did. After overriding Devise::SessionController, add the following code to it:

```
after_action :unauthenticated

protected

def unauthenticated
  flash[:alert] = t("devise.failure.#{request.env['warden'].message}") unless request.env['warden'].message.blank?
end
```

Also, on the same controller, copy and paste the code for the create method from your version of Devise, and remove the `!` from `warden.authenticate!`. Because you removed the `!`, now you have to check if the resource is nil, and redirect if it is. In my case, the create method ended up like this:

```
def create
  self.resource = warden.authenticate(auth_options)
  redirect_to root_path and return if resource.nil?
  set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  yield resource if block_given?
  respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end
```

Finally, you just have to print the flash messages on your views. I am using materialize, so I created a partial and added the following code to it (which you should customize to your own needs):

```
<% flash.each do |type, message| %>
  <% if type == "notice" %>
    <script id="toast">
      $(function() {
        Materialize.toast('<%= message %>', 4000);
      });
    </script>
  <% elsif type == "success" %>
    <script id="toast">
      $(function() {
        Materialize.toast('<%= message %>', 4000, 'green');
      });
    </script>
  <% elsif type == "alert" %>
    <script id="toast">
      $(function() {
        Materialize.toast('<%= message %>', 4000, 'orange');
      });
    </script>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I used @GuilPejon solution but I had to modify it slightly to make it work in my project. I didn't use `after_action` hook but put the method directly in the `create` method after `self.resource = warden.authenticate(auth_options)` line. 

Second modification I made:
I change `redirect_to`. My line: `redirect_to new_user_session_path and return if resource.nil?`
My `root_path` is was different than `new_user_session_path` and it was redirecting twice and overriding flash message from the `create` method on its way.

Answer (score 1):

Rails 5.1, Devise 4.4.3

Inside of a form, errors can be displayed with:

```
<% resource.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <%= msg %>
<% end %>
```