# Using Devise and Simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form

I am using devise in my rails app, I converted the devise views to use simple form.  When I attempt to sign up with an incorrect password format the flash messages for the password do not appear.  Flash messages appear for ever other field.  Does anyone know how to fix this problem.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel small-5 small-centered columns">
    <div class="row">
      <h2>Sign Up</h2>
      <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), 
      :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :email, label: "E-mail", :autofocus => true %>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-6 columns">
          <%= f.label :password, label: "Password" %>
          <%= f.password_field :password %>
        </div>
        <div class="small-6 columns">
          <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
          <div id="password-confirm">
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-6 columns">
          <%= f.input :last_name, label: "First Name" %>
        </div>
        <div class="small-6 columns">
         <%= f.input :first_name, label: "Last Name" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="sign-up">
          <%= f.label "Profile Photo" %><br>
          <%= f.file_field :avatar, label: "Profile Photo" %>
          <%= f.input :twitter_handle, label: "Twitter Url" %>
          <%= f.input :linked_in_url, label: "Linked In Url" %>
          <%= f.input :about_me, label: "About You (500 character max)" %>
        <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "button" %>
      <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you override your session controller ?

Comment: I added attributes the sessions controller but I am using that to verify non users.

Comment: but that should not be effecting it, i removed the session attributes and I still don't get the alerts for the password fields.

Comment: insert this in your view <%= devise_error_messages! %> and see if you are getting errors for password or not

Comment: I added the devise error messages but they dont show up in the simple for alerts I get the standard devise 2 errors prevented this from being saved with the bulleted list.

Comment: may be this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/4290891/1970061