# Devise errors not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise 3.2.3 with Rails 4.1.0.rc1, and I'm just trying to get errors to show up when an incorrect login occurs.

Here is the form:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="login-box">
    <h2>Sign in</h2>

    <%= form_for resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), html: { class: "form-horizontal" } do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>

      <fieldset>
        <%= f.email_field :email, class: "input-large col-xs-12", placeholder: "Email", :autofocus => true %>

        <%= f.password_field :password, class: "input-large col-xs-12", placeholder: "Password" %>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="field-spacer"></div>

        <%#= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "input-large col-xs-12", placeholder: "Confirm Password" %>

        <%= f.check_box :remember_me %><%= f.label :remember_me, "Remember Me?" %>

        <div class="field-spacer"></div>

        <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-primary col-xs-12" %>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <div class="text-center margin-top-10"><a href="<%= new_user_registration_path %>" class="underline">No account? Sign up here.</a></div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="field-spacer"></div>

      </fieldset>
    <% end %>

    <hr>
    <h3>Forgot Password?</h3>
    <p>
      No problem, <a href="<%= new_user_password_path %>" class="underline">click here</a> to get a new password.
    </p>  
  </div>
</div><!--/row-->

  </div><!--/row-->
```

And here is the trace:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-03 17:43:50 -0600
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"QuDKO+mP/iupA5k3ofeBO4Hr3mvFNZmyZooaBxNE0K4=", "user"=>{"email"=>"fsfa@gasgsa.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'fsfa@gasgsa.com'  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 7ms
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"QuDKO+mP/iupA5k3ofeBO4Hr3mvFNZmyZooaBxNE0K4=", "user"=>{"email"=>"fsfa@gasgsa.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_head.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered shared/_errors.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 69ms (Views: 8.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Any idea why this isn't returning the errors to the view?

**UPDATE 1:**

I put this file in:

```
module DeviseHelper
  def devise_error_messages!
    debugger
    return '' if resource.errors.empty?

    messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
    html = <<-HTML
    <div class="alert alert-error alert-block"> <button type="button"
    class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
      #{messages}
    </div>
    HTML

    html.html_safe
  end
end
```

And I used the debugger to see what was happening. When I hit submit with no information in the email or password fields (which should set off devise errors), the `resource` in that helper method doesn't have any errors. However, in the debugger console, if I run `resource.valid?`, then let it finish running, it creates the errors properly. What's the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise error messages are added to flash and should show as long as your application.html.erb file includes them, you can read the details in Ryan Bates excellent railscast

http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-devise-revised?view=asciicast

Also look at this post
[Devise not displaying error messge during an authentication failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112103/devise-not-displaying-error-messge-during-an-authentication-failure)

Comment: They're actually not being added to the flash messages.

Comment: Oh Ok, just in case you haven't seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112103/devise-not-displaying-error-messge-during-an-authentication-failure

Comment: That was it my friend, can you edit your original post to point to that link? I'll mark you as the winner if so :)