# Extending devise to support a JSON API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

We're upgrading an application that has two ways of authenticating users.

1. Controllers that have the `before_filter :authenticate_user!` callback and are accessed like a standard Rails site.
2. Controllers inside an API module that are accessed via JSON by client side applications. All the routes have the prefix `/api/session_id/` except the authenticate action that only has the prefix `/api`.

Both ways authenticate the users using the `User` model.

Is there a way to configure devise to support them both? How?

Note: I don't want to create users through JSON. I just want to authenticate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with [creating a new stategy to warden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223083/custom-authentication-strategy-for-devise).

On the `valid?` method i check if the `params[:controller]` comes from the api namespace.
This way I didn't touch the default devise authentication by http.

Answer (score 0):

I did this by overriding devise's session controller.

Add entry to routes for custom session controller:

```
 devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => 'sessions'}
```

And override the session controller:

```
  class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

    def create
      resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "sessions#failure")
      return sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)
    end

    def sign_in_and_redirect(resource_or_scope, resource=nil)
      scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
      resource ||= resource_or_scope
      sign_in(scope, resource) unless warden.user(scope) == resource
      respond_with do |format|
        format.json  {render :json => {:success => true} }
        format.any  {super}
      end
    end

    def failure
      respond_with do |format|
        format.json  {render:json => {:success => false, :errors => ["Login failed."]} }
        format.any  {redirect_to :back, :notice => "Wrong Email / Password" }
      end
      #return render:json => {:success => false, :errors => ["Login failed."]}
    end

  end
```

"[Rails & Devise: Override SessionsController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110047/rails-devise-override-sessionscontroller) is more discussion on the same subject.

Comment: how do I authenticate users using the post route /api/authenticate?

Comment: Add route,  devise_for :users do
  post "/api/authenticate" => "devise/sessions#create" end