# Devise Error Message Gender Custom

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, devise

I started working with Devise. Quite an awesome gem.  Reading through a neat [exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101641/rails-devise-handling-devise-error-messages) I was able to do a lot of interesting message customization.

NOW though, I'm running into an intriguing issue with customizing error messages based on noun gender for I18N purposes. Here, I have an error message containing %{resource}, where resource will sub in my model name (user). In French, the word coming before the %{resource} will vary depending on gender. Is there a way for me to branch out to a particular error message based on the %{resource} gender?

Comment: Would be helpful to see the custom code you're currently using for the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the human-readable model name by implementing the `model_name` instance method in your user model.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Naming.html

The model_name method has to return an object of type `ActiveModel::Name`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Name.html

You can customize this object to fit your i18n needs.