# Make Devise error messages appear

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, erb

In my application.html.erb file, I have

```
<% flash.each do |key,msg| %>
  <div class="message">
      <%= content_tag :div, msg %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Is there a way to make devise display it's error messages in there?

When I add `<%= devise_error_messages! %>` I get a `undefined local variable or method 'resource'` error.

Comment: Maybe this post will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101641/rails-devise-handling-devise-error-messages?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

In application.html.erb file

```
<% [:notice,:error,:info,:success,:alert].each do |key| %>
  <div class="message">
    <%= flash[key] %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to put a form_for with url so that devise will be able to check which resource it is referring to..

eg: <%form_for :post,:url=>post_path(@post) do |f|%>

Comment: Currently I have `<%= form_for @document, :remote => true do |f| %>`, why do I have to add the :url?