# Is rails devise's 'alert' safe from XSS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I've gone off and overridden devise's `devise_error_messages!` in the `DeviseHelper` module to return a differently formatted response as suggested here: [rails - Devise - Handling - devise_error_messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101641/rails-devise-handling-devise-error-messages)

However part of what I did was to include the results of `alert` like so:

```
def devise_error_messages!

  # if there aren't any errors, just return a blank string
  return '' if (resource.errors.empty? && !alert)

  # go through each of the messages and add a <br> onto the back of it
  messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| msg << "<br>" }.join

  # if there are also alerts, add that to the end of messages
  if alert
    messages << alert
  end

  # add div around messages
  messages = "<div class='errorbox'>" << messages << "</div>"

  # return messages in an html safe format
  messages.html_safe

end
```

This way I can have the `devise_error_messages!` in any page that needs them, and it'll just return the right answer. (E.g. devise's Sign Up form returns it's errors through `devise_error_message!` while the login form returns in through `alert`).

What I want to know is if I can be guaranteed that the output of `alert` won't lead to any Cross Site Scripting. I am assuming that the output of `resource.errors.full_messages` is safe since the original `devise_error_messages!` method returns `messages.html_safe` and I'd trust that they wouldn't let it be at risk of any XSS.

However since `alert` is suggested to be used in an erg output (e.g. `<%= alert %>`) where any injected code would be escaped by default, is there any occasion, where code could be injected in, thus making use of `.html_safe` potentially quite hazardous?

**tl;dr** - is it safe to use `alert.html_safe`?

Comment: Where does this `alert` come from?

Comment: Devise makes use of `flash[:alert]` and `flash[:notice]` to send warnings and it can be referenced as just `alert` or `notice`. When installing the Devise gem one of the instructions it gives is "Ensure you have flash messages in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb. For example:
`<p class="notice"><%= notice %></p><p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>`"
Not entirely sure where it comes from besides that, but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're modifying Devise's messages to add in user-provided content, or specifying custom flash messages with user-provided content, there's nothing to worry about.

All of Devise's flash messages are stored in `config/locales/devise.en.yml`.

Comment: Thanks, though is there a risk that at some time, if the creator of the server programmed something specific enough, that something like the `resource` in `"1 error prohibited this %{resource} from being saved:"` could be abused? I know this isn't going to be a problem with what users can do in my application, though more just out of general interest.

Comment: `resource` is the name of your Devise model (eg. user), so it can't really be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely an answer, since sevenseacat answered that it should be safe, though I was looking around a bit and found this quite relevant, hopefully it'll help people with similar problems.

If I were to be very pedantic about it, I could enclose `alert` inside `h()` like this:

```
if alert
  messages << h(alert)
end
```

This would ensure that any html in alert would be escaped while I can be sure that the rest of messages is HTML safe.

Comment: sometimes you might want to put your own HTML in a flash message, though.