# Error prohibited this user from being saved:

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, devise

I've been having an issue that I can't seem to fix

> 3 errors prohibited this user from being saved:
>
> - Email can't be blank
> - Password confirmation doesn't match Password
> - Password is too short (minimum is 8 characters)

I can't figure out how to get rid of the `3 error prohibited this user from being saved:`
All I want to display is the errors in bullets. Any ideas on how to go along with this? I'm using Devise, by the way.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Type it out, so we can all read it.

Comment: There is text in the post. The main issue is stated in the post @meagar

Comment: Going through the OPs posts it looks to be the latest @Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to get rid of the 3 error prohibited this user
>   from being saved

We override the `devise` helper to give us ultimate control over the errors we wish to show. [Here is a helpful resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101641/rails-devise-handling-devise-error-messages) which shows you how to achieve this

--

**Helper**

As per the answer by `Buck Doyle` & the attached resource, you may wish to do this:

```
#app/helpers/devise_helper.rb
module DeviseHelper
  def devise_error_messages!
     resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
  end
end
```

This will allow you to change your `devise views` to include the `devise_error_messages!` method:

```
#app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
```

Comment: @user302975: I can’t be sure, but I don’t think putting it in `ApplicationHelper` will truly override the Devise helper. That’s why I suggested putting it in an initialiser, and using the name `DeviseHelper`, which will definitely override the existing method.

Comment: So rename it to `DeviseHelper`? @BuckDoyle

Comment: I don't have a `DeviseHelper` only a `application_helper` and a `home_helper` @BuckDoyle

Comment: Add a *new* file here: `config/initializers/devise_helper_override.rb` and put the `module DeviseHelper` code that I put in my answer.

Comment: I get `<li>Email can&#39;t be blank</li><li>Password can&#39;t be blank</li>
Email` Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of `|msg| content_tag(:li, msg)`? Sorry for very basic question

Comment: Sorry, this would in your view - instead of just calling `<%= devise_error_messages!`, you could call `<%= raw(devise_error_messages!) %>`

Comment: @RichPeck `<%= raw(devise_error_messages!) %>` this doesn't seem to be working for me

Comment: Try changing to `resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join.html_safe`

Answer (score 2):

The Devise error messages come from a call to `devise_error_messages!`, which lives in a helper in [`devise/app/helpers/devise_helper.rb`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/helpers/devise_helper.rb). I found this out by running `bundle open devise` and looking at the views. The forms views call that helper method.

You could put this code in an initialiser to override it:

```
module DeviseHelper
  def devise_error_messages!
    return "" if resource.errors.empty?

    messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join

    html = <<-HTML
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <ul>#{messages}</ul>
    </div>
    HTML

    html.html_safe
  end
end
```

If you compare to the [original](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/helpers/devise_helper.rb), you’ll see I just removed the code that constructs the general error message and the `h2` that contains it.

Another option would be to [duplicate the views](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views) outside of the gem, then you can customise them with more granularity. You would run this and then edit the generated views:

```
rails generate devise:views
```

Comment: My original only has `module ApplicationHelper` and `end`. Is that normal?

Comment: Yes. The `DeviseHelper` lives inside the Devise gem. You won’t see it inside your application structure. You can use the `bundle open devise` command if you want to see the files included in the gem; you’ll find it inside `app/helpers` there. But I don’t recommend editing it, just override it elsewhere.

Comment: I left a comment on the other answer; how did you perform the override? I think you must put it in the `DeviseHelper` module, otherwise it won’t really override the original.

Comment: No luck. I've been able to get it working a bit with Rich Pecks post. But I get `<li>Email can&#39;t be blank</li><li>Password can&#39;t be blank</li>
Email`

Answer (score 0):

Honestly the cheapest way to do this (although not technically **removing** the header) is just to add the following in your CSS:

```
#error_explanation h2 {
  display: none;
}
```