# devise error message when wrong username/password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

My problem is that I do not see any error messages when Devise sign in failed. When this happens I got redirected to Devise::SessionsController#new which is not setting any errors

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-17 06:30:59 +0300
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4ZgT4DtyyNYNGHRbwCVASolL3CQEqIeMtPlOOy7EBik=", "user"=>{"username"=>"setdddd", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Войти"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 3ms
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4ZgT4DtyyNYNGHRbwCVASolL3CQEqIeMtPlOOy7EBik=", "user"=>{"username"=>"setdddd", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Войти"}
[]
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (40.0ms)
  Rendered application/_header.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered application/_footer.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 50ms (Views: 47.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

So the question is are there any switches in devise configuration that allow me to show error message to user, not just a redirect?

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101641/rails-devise-handling-devise-error-messages) post can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you outputting your [flash messages](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash) where appropriate?  It looks like devise sets flash[:notice] and flash[:alert] depending on the situation (i.e. failed login, etc).  It's up to you to ensure that you output those values to your page.  See the devise [README](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/README.md) for more details.

Comment: Thanx, my fault I missed this in documentation *(

Comment: This is a good answer. Simple problem but probably very common.