# Flash messages from a module in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I had my "create" method in my registration controller (devise) working just fine, flash messages and all.  Then I exported it out to a module, because I needed to access that method from another controller. It is working just fine, except the flash messages mysteriously stopped working. If I copy the code back to the registrations controller, the messages work fine again.

The controller:

```
require 'create_user'
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
  include CreateUser
  .
  # Stuff
  .
end
```

The module, located in app/modules:

```
module CreateUser
  def create
    flash[:notice] = "test" # obviously created to test the messages
    .
    # other stuff
    .
  end
end
```

I've tried changing CreateUser to a class, to have it be under the ApplicationsController, and the ActionBase itself as a module. But those messages do not work unless the code is directly in the controller. The flash messages are loaded directly from the layout, so I don't believe that is the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101641/rails-devise-handling-devise-error-messages

Comment: Never figured out why I can't use flash[:error], but I changed to using the notices/alerts/etc as part of my redirect_to, such as `redirect_to new_user_session_path, :notice => "Thank you for signing up. Please check your email to confirm your account before logging in."` - and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Never figured out why I can't use flash[:error], but I changed to using the notices/alerts/etc as part of my redirect_to, such as

```
redirect_to new_user_session_path, :notice => "Thank you for signing up. Please check your email to confirm your account before logging in."
```

and now everything works fine.