# Rails+Devise: No error message is shown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I'm making rails + Devise + Bootstrap app.
Basically it seems like working well, but when it gets wrong password
, no error message is shown like this.
[image]

I can't figure out why it happened and how to fix it.
Could you give me any advise for that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you add flash block for error in layout?

Comment: @uzaif Thanks. Nope. I haven't added that sort of feature. What and how to modify it?

Comment: I think you have to check the answer by @Sravan

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines above the yield block in your application layout as suggested in one comment.

```
    # In application.html.erb
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>

  # New code (allow for flash elements to be arrays)
  <% if msg.class == Array %>
    <% msg.each do |message| %>
      <%= content_tag :div, message, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>

    # old code
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>

  <% end %> #don't forget the extra end
<% end %>
```

Just add this code in the controller action, where you want to show the error messages,

```
flash[:notice] = flash[:notice].to_a.concat resource.errors.full_messages
```

[This link gives you many answers for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101641/rails-devise-handling-devise-error-messages)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. When I put the code above in the application.html.slim and put latter code into application_controller.rb, another error comes up like "Couldn't find Users::OmniauthCallbacksHelper, expected it to be defined in helpers/users/omniauth_callbacks_helper.rb". This time I need to put devise error in my app. And the model is User, so where to write the code above?